# How to address possible loss of data warning when transfering data between containers?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to transfer data from one container to another:

```
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    std::vector<int>   input_data;
    std::vector<float> output_data;

    output_data.insert(output_data.end(), input_data.begin(), input_data.end());
}
```

In VS2005, I get three C4244 warning in base.hpp saying "conversion from 'const int' to 'const float', possible loss of data."

Now I understand the warning, and it's a legitimate one. However in my particular case the loss of data is negligible. Is there any way to acknowledge the warning without having to do a loop like this?

```
for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator it; it != input_data.end(); ++it)
{
    output_data.push_back(static_cast<float32>(*it));
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do this _without_ a loop and explicit cast.

Comment: I think "transform" with the cast would work - you will need a cast to convert the type without warning, so you can't really avoid that. [Unless you turn off the warning, that is].

Comment: `std::transform(input_data.begin(), input_data.end(), std::back_inserter(output_data), [](int x) { return static_cast<float>(x); });`. Like Mats said, you can't really get rid of the warning without a cast. This looks like a "pick your poison" scenario to me.

Comment: @MatsPetersson /cc R. Martinho Fernandes, doesn't transform loop under the hood?

Comment: @Borgleader Yes, but so does `insert`.

Comment: @Borgleader so does `insert`. I think the point is to not write an explicit loop.

Comment: You do need an explicit cast. You may use `std::transform` instead of the loop, with the cast as the operation, wrapped in a lambda or a custom function object.

Comment: There is a loop, it's just hidden. In C++11 you could use for_each and a lambda which might be more up your street.

Comment: In VS you can get rid of the warning by using `#pragma warning(suppress: 4244)` just above the line where the problem is reported.

Comment: @OlivierD:  What's wrong with a loop and a cast?  Why do you want to hide the fact that you're transforming the data?

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: Nothing wrong with it. I just like the clarity and simplicity of insert. All the answers so far seem overly complicated, and using pragma in my case is not an option. I was hoping for something simple like std::max<float>(a, b), but it doesn't look like it exists.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Indeed, seems like "pick your poison." On a side-note, lamda expressions don't seem to be supported by VS2005. MarkB's use of a functor however seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using `boost::transform_iterator` with the existing insert?

```
struct to_float { float operator()(int x) const { return static_cast<float>(x); };
output_data.insert(output_data.end(), boost::make_transform_iterator(input_data.begin(), to_float()), boost::make_transform_iterator(input_data.end(), to_float()));
```

Answer (score 5):

In Visual Studio, you should be able to get around the warning by using the `#pragma` directives (it'd be perfectly valid to do this, as you are aware of the warning and just wish to suppress it), for instance, your main function would look something like:

```
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    std::vector<int>   input_data;
    std::vector<float> output_data;

#pragma warning(suppress: 4244)
    output_data.insert(output_data.end(), input_data.begin(), input_data.end());
}
```

This will suppress the warning C4244 for the following line of code (subsequent or preceding lines will still emit that warning). If you want to disable warning emissions for larger blocks of code, you may wish to look at the other [`#pragma warning` directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: You want to "push" and "pop" that warning so that you don't miss out when you actually want it later, tho'.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Doing it this way (with the `warning(suppress: 4244)`) only suppresses the warning for the following line

Comment: Ah, ok - so that's OK then.

Comment: Although this answer is the simplest so far, using `#pragma` isn't an option in my case.

Comment: @OlivierD Why is using `#pragma` not an option (if you don't mind my asking)?

Comment: @Shaktal Because I need to respect a coding standard that disallows hiding warnings using `#pragma`